# Derive an array from values of another array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this products array in an angular 2 component:

```
products = [{name: "product1", product_properties: [{name: "color", value: "blue"}, {name: "size", value: "small"}]}, 
            {name: "product2", product_properties: [{name: "color", value: "yellow"}, {name: "size", value: "medium"]}, 
            {name: "product3", product_properties: [{name: "color", value: "green"}, {name: "size", value: "large"}, 
            {name: "product4", product_properties: [{name: "color", value: "green"}, {name: "size", value: "small"}]} 
            {name: "product5", product_properties: [{name: "color", value: "yellow"}, {name: "size", value: "medium"}]
```

What is the most efficient way to loop over this array and derive an array which looks like the one below using typescript or javascript:

```
derivedArray = [{property_name: "color", values: ["blue", "yellow", "green"]}, 
                {property_name: "size", values: ["small", "medium", "large"]}]
```

Comment: can you specify what's the the logic of  ```derivedArray``` ? it's all uniqe values from all products or what ?

Comment: @shershen I have added products with duplicate `product_properties` to clarify on expected handling of duplicates. The `property_name`s and their corresponding `value`s should be unique even if the original array has duplicates

Comment: I add duplicates filtering to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array has some syntax errors, I fix them:

```
var inData = [
  {name: "product1", product_properties:[{name: "color", value: "blue"}, {name: "size", value: "small"} ]}, 
  {name: "product2", product_properties:[{name: "color", value: "yellow"}, {name: "size", value: "medium"}]}, 
  {name: "product3", product_properties:[{name: "color", value: "green"},  {name: "size", value: "large"}]}
];
```

Let's build hashmap of `property => values`:

```
var hash = inData.reduce((acc, p) => {
  p.product_properties.forEach(prop => {
    if (!acc[prop.name]) acc[prop.name] = [];
    if (!~acc[prop.name].indexOf(prop.value)) // filter duplicates
      acc[prop.name].push(prop.value);});
    return acc;
}, {});
```

And now build requested data structure:

```
Object.keys(hash).map(key => ({property_name: key, values: hash[key]}))
```

Result is:

```
[
  {"property_name":"color","values":["blue","yellow","green"]},     
  {"property_name":"size","values":["small","medium","large"]}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```js
var products = [{name: "product1", product_properties: [{name: "color", value: "blue"}, {name: "size", value: "small"}]}, 
            {name: "product2", product_properties: [{name: "color", value: "yellow"}, {name: "size", value: "medium"}]}, 
            {name: "product3", product_properties: [{name: "color", value: "green"}, {name: "size", value: "large"}]}];
var colorArray = [];
var sizeArray = [];
$.each(products,function(i,v){
var colorAttributes = v.product_properties[0];
var sizeAttributes = v.product_properties[1];
// check if attribute is already passed in the array using jQuery.inArray()
if(colorAttributes.name=="color" && $.inArray(colorAttributes.value,colorArray)==-1){
colorArray.push(colorAttributes.value);
}
if(sizeAttributes.name=="size" && $.inArray(sizeAttributes.value,sizeArray)==-1){
sizeArray.push(sizeAttributes.value);
}
});
var derivedArray = [{property_name: "color", values: colorArray}, 
                {property_name: "size", values: sizeArray}] ;
alert(JSON.stringify(derivedArray ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```